# Why can't I use 'isJust' in the lambda function in `foldr`?

Tags: haskell, fold, type-mismatch

I am currently writing an interpreter in haskell for a primitive programming language.
I am trying to see if the current program being analysed is correctly Typed before interpreting. Basically what I end up with is a list called `maybeList` that holds maps of the initialised variables if they are correct, or `Nothing`s if they don't, like this:

`[Maybe [(k,v)]]`

I am trying to fold over this list with this function

`foldr (\x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList`

From what I understand about Haskell and the `foldr` function, this should work. However, it gives me the error:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘Maybe a0’ 
> In the expression:
>
>  foldr (\ x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList
> ```

What I'm asking is why doesn't the compiler know that the  `isJust`  function returns a boolean, it keeps treating it as a  `Maybe a0`  type?

P.S. I understand that a simple  `elem Nothing maybeList`  will work in place of this. But I would like to understand why this doesn't work

Comment: Please include the whole error message (I think there should be two error messages). The parts that you have picked out are indeed confusing.

Comment: Please always include the **whole** error message. You've omitted the part where it showed you the expression and where exactly the error occurs in it.

Comment: When trying to understand a type error message, it’s often helpful consider small example inputs: `foldr (\x y -> isJust x && isJust y) True [Just 1, Just 2]` would mean `isJust (Just 1) && isJust (isJust (Just 2) && isJust True)`. Hopefully it’s clear how the extra `isJust` causes the type mismatch that the compiler is showing you. The answers you’ve gotten do a fine job of illustrating some ways to correct it, such as removing that `isJust`.

Answer (score 9):

The *reducing* function for `foldr` takes as second argument something of the same type as the initial element:

```
foldr (\x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList
--        \_______________________________/    
--                         |
--          these two must be the same type
```

So `y` is of type `Bool` but you are considering it of type `Maybe a`.

Therefore, `foldr (\x y -> (isJust x) && y) True maybeList` is the right solution.

Answer (score 5):

A `foldr` takes as second parameter the *accumulator*. Indeed, the type of `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: Foldable f => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> f a -> b
```

Here `b` is the type of the accumulator that goes conceptually from right-to-left, whereas `a` are the items of the list.

Since you work with `True` in `foldr (\x y -> isJust x && isJust y) True`, this thus means that the accumulator, and hence `y` also is of type `Bool`.

We can implement this with:

```
foldr (\x y -> isJust x && y) True maybeList
```

We however do not need `foldr` here. What you here determine is whether all the items are a `Just …`. We can thus work with [**`all :: Foldable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all):

```
all isJust maybeList
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in the part `isJust y`, `y` is the result of the fold for the tail of the list and therefore has type `Bool`. Just like the second argument `True` you are giving to the `foldr` function.

You can't call `isJust` on a value of type `Bool`. A simple fix would be to leave out the `isJust`.

The full error messages I get are:

```
<interactive>:3:16: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe a’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In the expression: (isJust x) && (isJust y)
      In the first argument of ‘foldr’, namely
        ‘(\ x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y))’
      In the expression:
        foldr (\ x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList
    • Relevant bindings include
        y :: Maybe a (bound at <interactive>:3:11)
        it :: Maybe a (bound at <interactive>:3:1)

<interactive>:3:42: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe a’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In the second argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘True’
      In the expression:
        foldr (\ x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList
      In an equation for ‘it’:
          it = foldr (\ x y -> (isJust x) && (isJust y)) True maybeList
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: Maybe a (bound at <interactive>:3:1)
```

Which shows that GHC interprets it the wrong way around. It thinks that you meant to have the result be of type `Maybe a0` for some `a0`. Then the second argument of `foldr`, namely `True`, has the wrong type and the result of the lambda has the wrong type.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `foldr` is

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

which means your lamda expression should take a `Bool` for it's second argument, whereas in your case it expects a `Maybe`.

Answer (score 3):

@Ismor has the correct explanation.

Note that Haskell has a library function*

```hs
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all f = foldr (\x y -> f x && y) True
```

So the solution of `foldr (\x y -> isJust x && y) True maybeList` is equivalent to `all isJust maybeList`.

Thus, the solution reads exactly like the specification: check to see if all elements of `maybeList` are `Just` => `all isJust maybeList`.

*
Technically, the type of `all` is

```hs
all :: (Foldable f) => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> Bool
```

So any type constructor which implements the `Foldable` typeclass can be checked to see whether all its elements satisfy a particular predicate. You can thus use this for trees, lists, Maybes, etc.

Comment: .... or `none isNothing` i.e. `not . elem Nothing`, as hinted/mentioned by OP. :)

Comment: @WillNess Although `not . elem Nothing` requires an `Eq` instance, so it's a little less general.